# LM741 saturation problem in MultiSim modeling

Tags: operational-amplifier, multisim

Since in my case Vs+ = 12V, Vs- = -12V

I expect that when I do an open loop OpAmp, the output should be limited by +- 12V, which is not the case in my simulation.

What is the problem?

P.S. with a closed loop everything works as expected.

[image]

Comment: what voltage does it limit at?

Comment: 2Andy, you can enlarge the image, it has 277 V upper bound and 2,68 kV lower. I am using a standard opAmp from the library of multisim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your op amp model is not a very accurate model. I'm guessing it does not include any limiting on the output voltage and is probably using a simple VCVS for the amplifier. If you don't like that behavior you should look for a better model.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to change to a different model and everything worked. Seems like a bug with this particular model in modelsim.